# How to create new column in dataframe with more than condition while having ability to scale the conditions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

df:

```
name      date                         type
apple     2018-01-01 00:00:00           a 
banana    2018-08-18 00:00:00           b
```

How do I create a new column with a certain value based on multiple conditions from other columns?

For example:

If `name` column equals `apple`, and `date` column equals `today`, and `type` column equals `a` THEN new column `id` equals `1`.

OR

If `name` column equals `banana`, and `date` column equals `today`, and `type` column equals `b` THEN new column `id` equals `2`.

new df will look like this:

```
name      date                         type       id
banana    2018-08-18 00:00:00           b          2
```

I want to be able to add more clauses based on column values that are in the df later on, so looking for an approach that is scalable.

currently I can do this with one column like so and one condition:

```
df.loc[df['name'].str.contains("Apple"),'id'] = 1
```

thank you in advance.

edit: 
have been trying this code but getting syntax error somewhere, not sure where.

new_df = df[((df['name'].str.contains('apple')) & (df['type'].str.contains('a')) & ((df['date'] = today)))]

Comment: First row is assigned 1 even though the date isn't today...

Comment: Also, you may want to declare a "default" id value that is assigned when no condition is met. Look into `numpy.select`.

Comment: I fixed the assignment, and added new code.

Comment: @RustyShackleford, what specifically do you want to accomplish by adding the `id` column here? do you want an id that allows you to group by unique name, date, type combos?

Comment: @AustinA the goal of the ID is that later in the code I can group certain rows and subset the dataframe further.

Comment: Have you considered just taking the hash of those three rows?

Comment: For business requirements that client has specific mappings for each of the IDs they want to use. Hash is out of the question

Comment: Jeez, is there any rhyme/reason to their mappings? i.e. are they easy to calculate or do you have a dictionary of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Convert "date" to `datetime`
2. Build your conditionals using `np.select`
3. Assign column and drop invalid assignments

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors='coerce')

today = pd.to_datetime('today')
ids = np.select( 
    [
        df.name.eq('apple') & df.date.eq(today) & df['type'].eq('a'),
        df.name.eq('banana') & df.date.eq(today) & df['type'].eq('b')
    ],
    [1, 2],
    default=np.nan
)
```

```
df = df.assign(ids=ids).dropna(subset=['ids'])
df
     name       date type  ids
1  banana 2018-08-18    b  2.0
```

Comment: Nice, thats a clear `np.select` problem, very readable. (PS: almost 100k ;) ) +1

Comment: So if there are 10 fruits and 10 types, doesn't this mean you'll have to manually list out 100 specific lines within the `np.select()`? If so, this does not seem scalable whatsoever.

Comment: @AustinA So you can interpret this question in two ways 1) explicitly assigning ids based on conditions, or 2) implicitly assigning ids for every unique combination. I've assumed the former, you've assumed the latter. I'll leave it up to OP to clarify what they want. If the latter, then you're right.

Comment: @coldspeed I am going the explicit route. Every condition will have a unique ID associated with it. The overall combinations can be scaled up or down.